# MediaPlayer.start() on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I've been working on creating an alarm app to run a music track that the user selects.
So, after the user selects the track, it is converted from Uri to String by `".toString"` method to be able to receive this Uri from a broadcast receiver so that it can be used in `MediaPlayer.create();` after converting it back to Uri

```
Uri.parse(String track);
```

The problem comes when i try to play this it doesn't work although when I tested this in another activity it worked fine and I checked the `uri.getPath()` it tells me the path of the track so the problem is not because Uri object is empty.

```
public class AlarmTrigger extends Activity {
    String trackPath;
    Uri trackUri;
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_alarm_trigger);

        trackPath = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Track path"); 
        //getIntent from BroadcastReceiver class
        trackUri = Uri.parse(trackPath);
        Toast.makeText(this, trackUri.getPath(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); // it works fine
        AlarmGoes();
    }

    public void AlarmGoes(){
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this,trackUri); 
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }
}
```

The stack-trace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.amr.mineapps.myapplication/com.amr.mineapps.awarm.AlarmTrigger}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.net.Uri.getScheme()' on a null object reference
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2747)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2808)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1541)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:165)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6375)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:912)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:802)

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.net.Uri.getScheme()' on a null object reference
at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1004)
at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:983)
at android.media.MediaPlayer.create(MediaPlayer.java:890)
at android.media.MediaPlayer.create(MediaPlayer.java:867)
at android.media.MediaPlayer.create(MediaPlayer.java:846)
at com.amr.mineapps.awarm.AlarmTrigger.onCreate(AlarmTrigger.java:40)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6845)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2700)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2808) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1541) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:165) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6375) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
```

Comment: This is not '`MediaPlayer.start()` on a null object reference'. It is `Uri.getScheme()` on a null object reference. Read the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

 // mediaPlayer.setDataSource(String.valueOf(myUri));
  mediaPlayer.setDataSource(AlarmTrigger.this,trackUri);
  mediaPlayer.prepare();   
  mediaPlayer.start();
```

In the previous activity, you should include `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` in the intent before sending data https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/08/10/uri-access-lifetime-shorter-than-you-might-think.html

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
```

Comment: Try it why? What's good about using two try/catch blocks where one would do? And what's good about ignoring two successive exceptions?

Comment: you are right, there is no need for two try catch blocks.

Comment: i get this error   04-02 17:34:00.616 20900-20900/com.amr.mineapps.myapplication W/MediaPlayer: Couldn't open content://com.mi.android.globalFileexplorer.myprovider/external_files/Music/Avicii%20-%20The%20Nights.mp3: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.fileexplorer.provider.FileExplorerFileProvider from ProcessRecord{7360cb5 20900:com.amr.mineapps.myapplication/u0a402} (pid=20900, uid=10402) that is not exported from uid 10107
04-02 17:34:00.620 20900-20900/com.amr.mineapps.myapplication E/MediaPlayer: Unable to create media player

Comment: it's a permission error; I will update the answer, take a look